# Getting a specific document from query Using Firebase Cloud functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im trying to get a user from a users collection with the most votes on a timed function. Ive been following the examples they have on the documentation, but still having trouble. Any thoughts?

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();

exports.testData = functions.pubsub.schedule("30 14 * * *")
    .timeZone("America/New_York")
    .onRun((context) => {
      const test = admin.firestore().collection("users").
          orderBy("votes").limit(1);

      try {
        console.log("document data:", test.data());
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", e);
      }
      return null;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code hasn't executed the query at all.  It is just building a query object, then calling a method data() which doesn't exist on that object (likely causing your code to crash).  I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) to learn how to use `get()` to execute the query.  It returns a promise that you must handle correctly.

```
return test.get()
    .then(snapshot => ...)
    .catch(error => ...)
```